# script to monitor for new files in a shared folder (windows host, linux guest)

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

I need to monitor a shared folder, in this specific case the host is windows and the guest is Ubuntu linux, for new files or a file that has changed.  Ideally the solution should work independent of the host machine or the machine that puts a file into the shared directory.  The new file will be the input for a different process.

The inotifywait set of tools don't detect new files if the files are created by the host and put into the shared folder.

What are my options?

Comment: After watching what do you want to do? If it is just a copying then periodically running `rsync` might work. However, I had issues with rsync running on a VirtualBox shared folder :(

Comment: I edited the question to reflect that I want to use the detected file as the input to a different process/shell script.  I am not using rsync in this case.

Comment: One challenge in this is identify when the file is completely copied from host to guest. @Paul-Nordin's answer is good if you can parse the output of the `watch` command. Another way could be to periodically run `ls -ctr | tail -1` to get the latest file. You can save file details in a variable and see if it ia new file and process appropriately,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use one of the polling tools that pre-date *dnotify* and *inotify*: [gamin](https://people.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/index.html) or [fam](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/fam/), along with something like [fileschanged](http://www.nongnu.org/fileschanged/) which is an `inotifywait`-like CLI tool. The gamin and fam projects are related, and both quite old (though gamin slightly less so).

For simple and portable tasks I have used [something like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63857/lock-folder-when-running-cron/63932) via cron:

```
if mkdir /var/lock/mylock; then
  ( cd /mnt/mypath; find . -type f -mmin +2 ) | myprocess
  rmdir /var/lock/mylock
else
  logger -p local0.notice "mylock found, skipping run"
fi
```

This uses primitive locking, and a GNU `find` conditional to only find files *older* than two minutes so I could be sure that files were completely written. In my case `myprocess` was an `rsync --remove-source-files --files-from=-` so that files were removed once they were processed.

This approach also lets you use `find -print0`/`xargs -0`/`rsync -0` to handle troublesome filenames.

If you must keep all (old and new) files in the same directory hierarchy, then building directory-listing snapshots and diff-ing them might also work for you:

```
if mkdir /var/lock/mylock; then
  ( 
    export LC_COLLATE=C  # for sort
    cd /mnt/mypath
    find . -type f -a \! -name ".dirlist.*" -printf '%p\0' | 
      while read -d '' file; do
        printf "%q\n" "${file}"  
      done > .dirlist.new
    [[ -f  .dirlist.old ]] && {
      comm -13 <(sort .dirlist.old) <(sort .dirlist.new) |
        while read -r file; do
          myprocess "${file}"
        done
    }
    mv .dirlist.new .dirlist.new
  )
  rmdir /var/lock/mylock
else
  logger -p local0.notice "mylock found, skipping run"
fi
```

This `bash` script:

1. uses `find -printf` to print a \0 (nul) delimited list of files
2. uses `read -d ''` to process that list, and `printf %q` to escape filenames where necessary
3. compares the new and previous .dirlist files
4. invokes `myprocess` with each new file (safely quoted)

(Also handling *modified* files would require slightly more effort, a double-line format with `find ... -printf '%p\0%s %Ts\0'` could be used, with associated changes to the `while` loops.)

Comment: Thank you!  That is a very good point about ensuring that the file has already been written.  In my case the writes over the shared directory should be fairly quick but the file sizes I am dealing with are somtimes more than 30MB so I wouldn't want to start using the file until it had finished writing.

Comment: I decided to use a filename creation token to determine if the larger file has finished copying.  The host copies both the large file and then a small file.  The small file is just a means to detect that the copying is done and the fine is ready to be processed.  Then I can just use the -f test to determine if the small file exists and use that to launch my logic.  I couple that with a crontab that runs a script which loops 5 times, sleeping 10 seconds to achieve a check every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

You need something that polls for file changes because if a file is modified on the Windows side, the Linux kernel is not going to know about it. There are a few existing applications that can help with that, such as Guard: http://guardgem.org/

Depending on your exact needs, you could just `watch` the file listing (adjusting n seconds to whatever is suitable):

```
watch --differences -n 10 ls -l </path/to/shared/dir>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are familiar with node.js and its ecosystem, you can use [this library](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar)
 to implement polling on a shared folder.

Comment: chokidar uses node fs.watch that uses.....drum roll..inotify on linux machine so this is not going to work on nfs,cifs,smb mounted directory. https://thisdavej.com/how-to-watch-for-files-changes-in-node-js/#using-fs.watch